# SSL Authentication Issue

Tags: java, linux, ssl, tomcat7

When I try to connect to an SSL-enabled web service, I get an ssl error. When I try to test the connection with openSSL, I get this returned:

`openssl s_client -debug -connect w.x.y.z:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x1e7ae00 [0x1e7b840] (121 bytes => 121 (0x79))
0000 - 80 77 01 03 01 00 4e 00-00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00   .w....N... ..9..
0010 - 38 00 00 35 00 00 16 00-00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0   8..5............
0020 - 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 00-2f 03 00 80 00 00 05 00   ..3..2../.......
0030 - 00 04 01 00 80 00 00 15-00 00 12 00 00 09 06 00   ................
0040 - 40 00 00 14 00 00 11 00-00 08 00 00 06 04 00 80   @...............
0050 - 00 00 03 02 00 80 00 00-ff de aa 66 42 43 9f cf   ...........fBC..
0060 - e0 43 1b ec 72 9a 8b 24-9d 43 55 b0 d2 2f cf 1a   .C..r..$.CU../..
0070 - 22 01 aa be ec 11 4a a4-8c                        ".....J..
read from 0x1e7ae00 [0x1e80da0] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
17823:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:`

It looks like it tries to connect with SSLv2 or SSLv3, but it can't. The connection can be established with SSLv1. I have this web service running in a tomcat instance, that might not have SSLv2 or SSLv3 enabled. How can I enable SSLv2 or SSLv3 on tomcat?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>   80 77 01 03 01...
> ```
>
> ...It looks like it tries to connect with SSLv2 or SSLv3, but it can't.

The `03 01` in the debug output shows that it is using TLS 1.0. The bytes in front of this are length (2 byte) and type (ClientHello = 01) and thus indicate a [SSL 2.0 compatible handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-87).

> The connection can be established with SSLv1.

There is no SSLv1. You probably mean TLS 1.0 or later (i.e. TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2)

> ```
> 17823:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
> ```

This indicates that the server is simply closing the connection. There might be a lot of reasons for this, like wrong protocol or no common ciphers. In your test with openssl it might also be a missing [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension, because some servers close the connection or throw some error if they don't get this extension. Use `-servername` option to specify the expected hostname.

Apart from that the server simply closes the connection and does not sent any error information. Thus you need to look at the server side for more detailed error information (log files etc).

> How can I enable SSLv2 or SSLv3 on tomcat?

You better don't. SSL 2.0 (SSLv2) is definitely insecure and SSL 3.0 (SSLv3) is considered insecure too (POODLE attack). You should not use any of these for production systems. Most clients do not support SSL 2.0 at all and more and more disable support for SSL 3.0 by default. And I doubt that the problem you have with your server can be solved this way.

Comment: Nitpick: I'd say the client *offers* TLS1.0, but it's not in use until the server agrees -- which it doesn't in this case. JSSE (all versions I've checked) understands SSL2-hello; even if you disable the protocol(s) it responds with one of several alerts, not just socket close. OpenSSL, which Tomcat uses for the 'native' aka APR option, also understands SSL2-hello and gives at least an alert in nearly all cases; the only exception I can find is if the app calls a single-version *method*, not the (confusingly-named) SSLv23 method with restricted *protocols* -- but I don't *think* APR does that.

Comment: @Jay37 you are apparently using a very old and nearly obsolete (support ends in 4 months) release of OpenSSL, 0.9.8. Try adding `-tls1` to get it to use the newer *format* hello and see what difference that makes. If possible try to get OpenSSL 1.0.1 or 1.0.2; those support up to TLS1.2, and no longer use the SSL2 format (from the command line), and thus can work with servers that meet current standards and best practices. (It doesn't have to be on the same machine; you can get openssl and run `s_client` on any other machine with network access to your server.)

Comment: Thanks for all the input! Right now, this is just for testing, and the tomcat server is just a test server to be able test the web service that is being run. In production, it won't be on tomcat. I can't modify the client that is generating the web service request, but can modify tomcat for the server. The client is just a sample client running on a VM, so I'm sure that the production client has different SSL settings. Right now, I'm just trying to get this to work in order to move on with my development of the web service.